# Facebook payment returns error code 200 with status "Request aborted"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an app on facebook which users buy credits to play in a game.
For some reason when I make the call to facebook API like this:

```
var obj =
{
    method: 'pay',
    action: 'purchaseitem',
    product: product URI
    request_id: requestID
};

FB.ui(obj, function (data) {
...
});
```

In the callback function I get data object which contains:
data.error_code = '200';
data.error_message = 'Request aborted'

Anyone can please advise why is this happening?

Comment: This looks like some issue the request and CSRFs. Are you testing this on a local machine, or an website? Has the browser enabled/disabled cookies?

Comment: I can't reproduce it myself. 
I can see it's happenning from error logs I inserted after seeing the error rate in Facebook Insight graphs. That's all I have....

Comment: If you disable cookies in your browser, do you also get the error?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but if someone still needs an answer, I believe that the issue is related to the fact that the end users are double-clicking the button, hence creating a call to another Ajax request and therefor the first request is being aborted.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If fast or accidental double clicks are an issue due to performance or user end error perhaps we need to try to use javascript to remove button from DOM on user click removing any chance of the error.